# Bootstrap, keeping header height with <strong> element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, height

I have a collapsible sidebar, and when it's collapsed the header shrinks to display the letters 'J  L'. This works but I can't find middle ground between the empty header and then adding my letters in.

So if I comment out my  element to where no text is there, the empty header fits the 40px height perfectly.

But when I add in the letters It is taller than 40px. So I know my height is working for the header CSS but I need it to stay 40px and incorporate the J L as a strong element that is totally centered.

Here are images showing the problem:

Before
[image: Before]
After
[image: After]

So I need to incorporate the Strong element but keep the 40px height so the green bars continue to touch

```css
 #sidebar.active .sidebar-header{
     height:40px !important;
    }

    #sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<nav id="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-header">
   <strong>J L</strong>
  </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: You could try using `line-height:40px` tomake the text respect the height of the div?

Comment: If you can include some more code so that we can replicate your issue then we can provide more constructive help

Answer (score 1):

Add a `line-height` to your `<strong>` element, like so:

```
#sidebar.active .sidebar-header{
        height:40px !important;
    }

    #sidebar.active .sidebar-header strong {
        display:block;
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;

    }
```

Comment: Unforunately that didn't do the trick, even with adding !important to it. I feel like it's beeing overridden somehow by bootstrap

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: Ok this is weird: So with your revised code, it actually puts a bigger difference of white space than my before picture above. So when I remove the line-height, it goes back down to the more narrow margin under the J L in my pic above